# Какой файл конфигурации выбрать?

Tags: linux, windows, хранение-данных

Часто для своих приложений мне нужно использовать файл где я буду хранить сохраняемые данные для настройки моего приложения (проще говоря конфигурационный файл). И пока не нашел своего идеального варианта. Нужно что бы данный файл удовлетворял следующим требованиям:

1. Приложению необходимо легко записывать данные в него и также легко считывать.
2. При открытии файла человеком, данные должны быть легкочитаемы и понятны, даже если файл достаточно большой
3. Должен существовать простой способ записи человеком в конфигурационный файл, с минимальной возможностью внесения ошибок, независимо от платформы в которой данный файл открыт для редактирования.

Например XML не подходит под данные требования. Он хорошо считывается и можно вести запись в своем приложении. Но например человеку уже не просто разобраться, а редактировать файл так вообще нужно либо в специальном софте, либо есть большая вероятность допустить ошибку.

Я использую CSV. Тоже не идеальный вариант, но он хотя бы позволяет видеть конфигурацию в виде таблицы и его можно отредактировать в любом текстовом редакторе (хотя не очень просто).

А какой файл конфигурации вы используете?

Comment: `ini`-файл вроде не плохо подходит

Comment: Если конфигурационный файл не содержит иерархических настроек - то формат INI идеален. Иначе - реестроподобный формат с FQPath (который в общем по сути тот же бессекционный INI).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ini подходит для структур без вложенности. Вложенность можно нарисовать ссылками на новые структуры. Не очень удобен с массивами.

[yaml](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) подходит для данных любой вложенности, удобен с массивами, толерантен к запятым и кавычкам. Но есть требования к форматированию.

Не рекомендую json из-за кавычек в ключах и потеренных запятых. XML при редактировании не удобен из-за закрывающих тегов.

Comment: [toml](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) подходит для данных любой вложенности, удобен с массивами, толерантен к запятым и отступам, а то что строки нужно заворачивать в кавычки так это наоборот хорошо (:

Comment: Сам пользовался YAML много раз. Есть отличная библиотека для С: https://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML (есть реализации для очень многих ЯП). Настоятельно рекомендую.

Comment: @andreymal  Во как раз томл хотел порекомендовать ;)